# Importing ctypes and tempfile causes 'Aborted' on execution?

Tags: python, ctypes

I stumbled across the following in one of my modules and am trying to understand what is happening.   At the most basic level I have a file like this:

```
# myfile.py
#
import ctypes
import tempfile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

executing

```
$ python myfile.py
```

gives

```
Aborted
```

as output, but if I simply switch the order of the imports, importing tempfile first, it executes without any output.

Where does the "Aborted" come from? Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce (tested on OS-X 10.5.8 using python 2.7.3).  What version of python?  What OS?  Do you have a `ctypes.py` or `tempfile.py` somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH` (e.g. the current directory?)

Comment: Should have said, Python 2.7.3 on Cygwin.  Doesn't happen on Windows (Python v. 2.7.2), must be something strange with Cygwin

Comment: try `python -vv` and [`faulthandler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/) or gdb to see where the error happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try from Python interpeter?:

```
>>>import ctypes
```

And

```
>>>import tempfile
```

I think you should isolate first the error in order to trace it.